# How to implement Canny Edge Detector in Java and android studio

Tags: java, android, image-processing, canny-operator

I had been looking up code for canny edge detection in android studio or java. Could anyone please explain me how the method works and also a sample code for the canny edge detector?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [open-imaj](http://www.openimaj.org/apidocs/org/openimaj/image/processing/edges/CannyEdgeDetector.html). They have provided documentation/javadocs etc.

You can also get the source code at [Maven Central Repository](http://search.maven.org/)

(I am unable to post this as a comment)